# Rails how to controller redirect if boolean is true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm trying to create a object and turn the boolean to true and redirect after that
in any case the log show error.

someone know how?

```
class BrandsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @brand = current_user.build_brand(params[:brand])
  end

  def create
    @brand = current_user.build_brand(params[:brand])


    if @brand.save

      redirect_to "#{new_user_path}?branded=#{@current_user.branded[1]}"

flash[:success] = "thank's".html_safe
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: `@brand.save` will be a boolean unless you've done something that generates an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure specifically what's wrong there, but there's some things that are not really done in the proper Rails style. Here's a reworked version that's more conventional:

```
class BrandsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :build_brand, only: [ :new, :create ]

  def new
  end

  def create
    @brand.save!

    flash[:success] = "Thanks!"

    redirect_to new_user_path(branded: @current_user.branded[1])

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    render(action: :new)
  end

protected
  def build_brand
    @brand = current_user.build_brand(params[:brand])
  end
end
```

Using `save!` generates an exception if there's a problem, so you can avoid the `if` altogether. Then you can handle the case where it couldn't save by re-rendering the form. You can also move duplicated code into a `before_action` handler where you can do it once.

Move your `html_safe` call into the template when you reference `flash[:success]`. It's premature to do escaping here. In some cases you may be sending JSON instead and you don't want it in HTML form.